# Confused about how to populate select element

Tags: php

I have this function  that fetches the authors from db

```
function loadAuthors(){
    $db=new DbConnect;
    $con=$db->connect();

    $stmt=$con->prepare("select * from authors");
    $stmt->execute();
    $authors=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $authors;
}
```

I am calling this function here

```
function fetch(){

    $result='';

    $authors=loadAuthors();
    while (list($k,$v)=each($authors)) {
        $result.='<option value="'.$k.'">' .$v.'</option>';
    }
    return $result;



}
```

I am trying to  populate the options of a select element but It gives me this output

```
Array
Array
```

Comment: What do you get if you print_r($authors)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can debug your output with `var_dump()`.
Your `loadAuthors` returns an array containing asociatetive arrays.
Also you then have define what columns you want to display.
An author is an object.

Smth like this should work:

```
/* ... */
foreach ($authors as $author) {
  $result.='<option value="'.$author["column_name"].'">' .$author["column_name"].'</option>';
}
/* ... */
```

Comment: I would also advise to use foreach, since each() is now deprecated

https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecations_php_7_2

@CodeSpirit answer should work fine.

Comment: From the link: "The each() function is inferior to foreach in pretty much every imaginable way, including being more than 10 times slower. The continued existence of this function poses a problem for certain language changes. For example the https://wiki.php.net/rfc/notice-for-non-valid-array-container RFC had to exclude list(), because the typical usage of each relies on the fact that you can access array offsets on false without a warning."

Comment: @Code Spirit Thank you for your help